# How to manipulate only one record with group by clause MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have below table :
[image]

What I want to do is deduct one hour from time difference of "punch_in_utc_time" and "punch_out_utc_time" if it is above 5hrs and this should only be done once if we have multiple records per day having time difference above 5hrs. Also need to skip the deduction if it has "1" for "has_overnight_shift". After doing all these manipulations I need to "group by" by  "employee_id" as well. I could deduct one hour from all the records but not only once per day. Could you help me out..?

If you need csv data :

"1","54","2017-10-05 12:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-05 18:00:00","2017-10-05 18:29:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-05 23:59:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"2","54","2017-10-05 18:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-06 00:00:00","2017-10-06 00:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-06 06:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","1"
"3","54","2017-10-06 02:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-06 08:00:00","2017-10-06 06:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-06 12:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"4","54","2017-10-07 00:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-07 06:00:00","2017-10-07 06:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-07 12:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"5","54","2017-10-07 07:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-07 13:00:00","2017-10-07 13:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-07 19:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"6","54","2017-10-08 02:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-08 08:00:00","2017-10-08 04:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-08 10:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"7","54","2017-10-08 05:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-08 11:00:00","2017-10-08 06:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-08 12:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"8","54","2017-10-08 07:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-08 13:00:00","2017-10-08 09:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-08 15:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"9","54","2017-10-15 12:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-15 18:00:00","2017-10-15 18:29:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-15 23:59:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"10","54","2017-10-15 18:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-16 00:00:00","2017-10-16 00:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-16 06:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","1"
"11","54","2017-10-16 02:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-16 08:00:00","2017-10-16 06:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-16 12:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"12","54","2017-10-17 00:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-17 06:00:00","2017-10-17 06:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-17 12:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"13","54","2017-10-17 07:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-17 13:00:00","2017-10-17 13:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-17 19:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"14","54","2017-10-18 02:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-18 08:00:00","2017-10-18 04:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-18 10:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"15","54","2017-10-18 05:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-18 11:00:00","2017-10-18 06:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-18 12:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"16","54","2017-10-18 07:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-18 13:00:00","2017-10-18 09:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-18 15:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"17","54","2017-10-19 12:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-19 18:00:00","2017-10-19 18:29:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-19 23:59:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"18","54","2017-10-19 18:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-20 00:00:00","2017-10-20 00:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-20 06:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","1"
"19","54","2017-10-20 02:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-20 08:00:00","2017-10-20 06:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-20 12:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"20","54","2017-10-21 00:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-21 06:00:00","2017-10-21 06:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-21 12:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"21","54","2017-10-21 07:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-21 13:00:00","2017-10-21 13:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-21 19:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"22","54","2017-10-22 02:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-22 08:00:00","2017-10-22 04:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-22 10:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"23","54","2017-10-22 05:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-22 11:00:00","2017-10-22 06:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-22 12:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"
"24","54","2017-10-22 07:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-22 13:00:00","2017-10-22 09:30:00",NULL,"5.5","2017-10-22 15:00:00","PUNCHED OUT","0"

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Expected output will help more here. And try to put actual data instead of image. It will help us to make dummy query.

Comment: Added csv data here.

Comment: Please look at the formatted version of your post, below the editing window, and edit appropriately. Please read & act on [mcve]--which includes an executable example with specification, and [using text, not images/links, for text (including tables)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Also [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'--including showing what you have been able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got solved my problem. What I did was after doing this manipulation, I created a temporary table on the fly and populate these new data and then applied the group by conditions. 
Thanks for your time mates..